# Efficient column processing in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a very large number of columns (>30000).

I'm filling it with `1` and `0` based on the first column like this:

```
for column in list_of_column_names:
  df = df.withColumn(column, when(array_contains(df['list_column'], column), 1).otherwise(0))
```

However this process takes a lot of time. Is there a way to do this more efficiently? Something tells me that column processing can be parallelized.

Edit:

Sample input data

```
+----------------+-----+-----+-----+
|  list_column   | Foo | Bar | Baz |
+----------------+-----+-----+-----+
| ['Foo', 'Bak'] |     |     |     |
| ['Bar', Baz']  |     |     |     |
| ['Foo']        |     |     |     |
+----------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: can you provide with sample input data and explain a little bit more ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan added sample input data. Currently spark processes each column sequentially, which is slow. My question is about making this processing faster.

Comment: Spark handles tall tables (lots of rows) really well, but it's not as great with wide tables (lots of columns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might approach like this,

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

exprs = [F.when(F.array_contains(F.col('list_column'), column), 1).otherwise(0).alias(column)\
                  for column in list_column_names]

df = df.select(['list_column']+exprs)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing specifically wrong with your code, other than very wide data:

```
for column in list_of_column_names:
    df = df.withColumn(...)
```

only generates the execution plan.

Actual data processing will concurrent and parallelized, once the result is evaluated.

It is however an expensive process as it require *O(NMK)* operations with N rows, *M* columns and *K* values in the list.

Additionally execution plans on very wide data are very expensive to compute (though cost is constant in terms of number of records). If it  becomes a limiting factor, you might be better off with `RDDs`:

- Sort column array using `sort_array` function.
- Convert data to `RDD`.
- Apply search for each column using binary search.

Answer (score 2):

`withColumn` is already distributed so *a faster approach would be difficult to get other than what you already have*. you can try defining a `udf` function as following

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t

def containsUdf(listColumn):
    row = {}
    for column in list_of_column_names:
        if(column in listColumn):
            row.update({column: 1})
        else:
            row.update({column: 0})
    return row

callContainsUdf = f.udf(containsUdf, t.StructType([t.StructField(x, t.StringType(), True) for x in list_of_column_names]))

df.withColumn('struct', callContainsUdf(df['list_column']))\
    .select(f.col('list_column'), f.col('struct.*'))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+-----------+---+---+---+
|list_column|Foo|Bar|Baz|
+-----------+---+---+---+
|[Foo, Bak] |1  |0  |0  |
|[Bar, Baz] |0  |1  |1  |
|[Foo]      |1  |0  |0  |
+-----------+---+---+---+
```

**Note: `list_of_column_names = ["Foo","Bar","Baz"]`**