# Pyspark apply parallel summary function to all columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to apply summary and customized stats functions to all columns, independently and *in parallel*.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand, randn
df = sqlContext.range(0, 10).withColumn('uniform', rand(seed=10)).withColumn('normal', randn(seed=27))
```

I have tried to look for answers such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50414300/efficient-column-processing-in-pyspark) and [here](https://changhsinlee.com/pyspark-udf/), but they seem to be giving one value for each row. It seems that `udf` and `withColumns` are solutions, but I am not sure how to put together to achieve something similar to this :

```
df.describe().show()
+-------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|summary|                id|            uniform|              normal|
+-------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|  count|                10|                 10|                  10|
|   mean|               4.5| 0.5215336029384192|-0.01309370117407197|
| stddev|2.8722813232690143|  0.229328162820653|  0.5756058014772729|
|    min|                 0|0.19657711634539565| -0.7195024130068081|
|    max|                 9| 0.9970412477032209|  1.0900096472044518|
+-------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Let's say we have a couple of dummy functions for summary

```
def mySummary1(df_1_col_only):
   return mean(df_1_col_only)*second_largest(df_1_col_only)

def mySummary2(df_1_col_only):
   return 10th_decile(df_1_col_only)/median(df_1_col_only)
```

so that when applying in parallel to all columns

```
df.something_that_allow_spark_parallel_processing_all_columns(column_list, [mean, mySummary1, mySummary2])
```

and produce (preferably the following, or the transposed)

```
+-------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
    |col_name|            mean|       mySummary1|            mySummary2|
    +-------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
    |  id|                10|                 10|                  10|
    |uniform|               4.5| 0.5215336029384192|-0.01309370117407197|
    | normal|2.8722813232690143|  0.229328162820653|  0.5756058014772729|
     +-------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

I would want to utilize the parallel power of Spark to parallelize in both columns list and inside each *mySummaryxxx* functions.

Another question is what should my df_1_col_only be like for efficiency ? 1-column Spark dataframe ? Is there a way of not copying of duplicating the original dataframe into a bunch of 1-column dataframe ?

Comment: You could union a row to dataframe returned by describe. Something like: `df.describe().union(df.select(lit("cust_stat1").alias("summary"), *[myCustomerFunction(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns])`. Hard to say more without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) that shows exactly what types of custom stats you want to compute.

Comment: @Pault: Just add some info to my question. I am not sure your approach will parallellize the column processing. _for_ gives that away. The parallel processing is crucial,

Comment: df.describe takes a list of the stats you want it to return and empty argument returns all stats. To get aggregate stats in parallel fashion use UDAFs, finally you can union the two dataframes to get a dataframe in the format you want

Comment: How would you simulate panda_udf in Spark<=2.2 (due to company's infra). I would like to parallel process columns, and in each column make use of Spark to parallel process rows. Let's say I have certain stat that I want to apply per column. collect_list gives list, is it efficient to convert to new Spark DF ? def myFunc(d_list): sdf = spark.createDataframe(d_list); return sdf.map(...).reduceByKey(...); and called on two columns df.agg(collect_list('col1').alias('col1'),collect_list('col2').alias('col2') ) .withColumn('col1_', myUdf('col1')).withColumn('col2_', myUdf('col2'))